# VirtualBox 7.0 Can't enumerate USB devices / No devices available

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox, group

Upon the launch of VirtualBox (exact version `7.0.10-158379~Ubuntu~jammy`) on my Linux Mint 21.3, I am *greeted* with a message in the upper-right corner:

> Can't enumerate USB devices

and if I try to connect a USB device in the VM settings I get:

> No devices available

---

I know there should be and there is `vboxusers` user group, but it appears to have no members:

```
$ grep vboxusers /etc/group
vboxusers:x:129:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, adding the user to the group `vboxusers` appears to do the trick.

---

For the `$USER` variable to be correct, the following command is constructed to be run by the user who runs VirtualBox.

```bash
sudo usermod -aG vboxusers $USER
```

Note, that it is needed to log out of the desktop and log back in. Afterward, it should work.